# Install SFTP on Debian Lenny use root user to login

Tags: installation, debian, ftp, sftp, lamp

I am new to linux. I have a server that I have successfully installed Debian Lenny on and everything else needed for a LAMP server.

But I am unsure how to setup FTP. My first attempt went horribly wrong had a load of permission issues.

How can I give full read/write access to my WWW folder.

The more in-depth the answer the better. I feel like such a noob.

Comment: What kind of FTP server do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, SFTP is NOT FTP over SSH. To configure SFTP you need to do it through the ssh configuration file. Also, you need to make sure you have the proper permission on your folder. It is not wise to supply FULL access to anything, make sure you do it wisely. This should help you with fundamentals. www.linux-tutorial.net

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Setting_up_an_FTP_server_on_Debian) should give you what you need.
[edit] Actually your question refers to SFTP.  Your box will already have sshd running which will be usable for SFTP.  Look in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for server configuration.  Or refer to the link if you meant FTPd (which IMHO you shouldn't be using in this day and age).

Further, if you want to allow access to a folder, you may want to check [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny) out.

Comment: How do I give the user root ftp access

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scp file.tgz root@the.ipof.your.server:/root/file.tgz
```

You do *not* want root to be able to login to a public FTP server :)